# PySpark row to struct with specified structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, types, type-conversion

This is my initial dataframe:

```py
columns = ["CounterpartID","Year","Month","Day","churnprobability", "deadprobability"]
data = [(1234, 2021,5,12, 0.85,0.6),(1224, 2022,6,12, 0.75,0.6),(1345, 2022,5,13, 0.8,0.2),(234, 2021,7,12, 0.9,0.8)]

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("client_id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("year", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("month", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("day", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("churn_probability", DoubleType(), False),
    StructField("dead_probability", DoubleType(), False)
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image: First dataframe]

Then I do some transformations on the columns (basically, separating out the float columns into before decimals and after decimals columns) to get the intermediary dataframe.

```py
abc = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],int(x[4]),int(x[4]%1 * pow(10,9)), int(x[5]),int(x[5]%1 * pow(10,9)) )).toDF(['client_id','year', 'month', 'day', 'churn_probability_unit', 'churn_probability_nano', 'dead_probability_unit', 'dead_probability_nano'] )

display(abc)
```

[image: Intermediate dataframe]

Below is the final desired dataframe (this is just an example of one row, but of course I'll need all the rows from the intermediary dataframe.

```py
sjson = {"clientId": {"id": 1234 },"eventDate": {"year": 2022,"month": 8,"day": 5},"churnProbability": {"rate": {"units": "500","nanos": 780000000}},"deadProbability": {"rate": {"units": "500","nanos": 780000000}}}
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([sjson])).select("clientId", "eventDate", "churnProbability", "deadProbability")

display(df)
```

[image: Final Desired Dataframe]

How do I reach this end state from the intermediary state efficiently for all rows?

End goal is to use this final dataframe to write to Kafka where the schema of the topic is a form of the final desired dataframe.

Comment: the pics are very small but that looks like a json string. if so, structs can be created using the `struct` function and then apply `to_json` to convert the struct to the target json string

Comment: I didn't need to use to_json, just struct worked.

Comment: which platform are you using? a struct in my jupyter notebooks is output as `{'ele1', 'ele2'}` or `{'ele1'}`.

Comment: Pyspark within Databricks. I doubt if it is anything to do with the Platform though. I also posted the answer. Have you tried executing the scripts for dataframe creation, intermediate dataframe and the final answer I have?

Comment: yeah, i did. the output on jupyter notebook does not look like the one you've pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably eliminate the use of `rdd` logic (and again `toDF`) by using just one `select` from your original `df`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

defg = df.select(
    F.struct(F.col('client_id').alias('id')).alias('clientId'),
    F.struct('year', 'month', 'day').alias('eventDate'),
    F.struct(
        F.struct(
            F.floor('churn_probability').alias('unit'),
            (F.col('churn_probability') % 1 * 10**9).cast('long').alias('nanos')
        ).alias('rate')
    ).alias('churnProbability'),
    F.struct(
        F.struct(
            F.floor('dead_probability').alias('unit'),
            (F.col('dead_probability') % 1 * 10**9).cast('long').alias('nanos')
        ).alias('rate')
    ).alias('deadProbability'),
)
defg.show()
# +--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
# |clientId|    eventDate|churnProbability| deadProbability|
# +--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
# |  {1234}|{2021, 5, 12}|{{0, 850000000}}|{{0, 600000000}}|
# |  {1224}|{2022, 6, 12}|{{0, 750000000}}|{{0, 600000000}}|
# |  {1345}|{2022, 5, 13}|{{0, 800000000}}|{{0, 200000000}}|
# |   {234}|{2021, 7, 12}|{{0, 900000000}}|{{0, 800000000}}|
# +--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Good point to remove the rdd logic and use select.  However, the resultant dataframe in your answer does not match to the expected, but this is a good push in the right direction.

Comment: What exactly does not match? As far as I can tell, this one and your current solution, both return the same result.

Comment: the final output does not have  "id" in clientId, "Year", "Month", "Day" in eventDate and all the json looking output in the columns . You can refer to the screenshot of my answer. e.g. under event date -> {"year: : 2022, "month": 5, "day": 13} whereas the one you have returns {2021,5,13} under eventDate. Same for the other columns

Comment: Have you tested it? I think it is because of preview differences in different platforms. I have tested both of our answers. In my platform, both of them return the same structure/ data.

Comment: Yes, I did. Could be the platform. If you look at my screenshot vs yours, you will see the difference. I am using Pyspark within Databricks.

Comment: Now that I think of it, if you see - in my answer, I used a function called display, which is native to Databricks. I will try to use just “show” and then check.

Comment: It was indeed that. Display is what changes the format.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough testing, we both learned something out of this

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to solve this using structs , without using to_json

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

defg = abc.withColumn(
    "clientId",
    f.struct(
        f.col("client_id").
        alias("id")
    )).withColumn(
  "eventDate",
  f.struct(
     f.col("year").alias("year"),
     f.col("month").alias("month"),
     f.col("day").alias("day"),
  )
).withColumn(
"churnProbability",
  f.struct( f.struct(   
         f.col("churn_probability_unit").alias("unit"),
         f.col("churn_probability_nano").alias("nanos")
        ).alias("rate")
          )
 ).withColumn(
"deadProbability",
  f.struct( f.struct(   
         f.col("dead_probability_unit").alias("unit"),
         f.col("dead_probability_nano").alias("nanos")
        ).alias("rate")
          )
  ).select ("clientId","eventDate","churnProbability", "deadProbability" )
```

[image: end dataframe]